# What context should I pass to read from assets from another java class?

Tags: android

I have 2 Java files (CreateMyDb.java,ReadfromAssets.java).
In ReadfromAssets.java, I have the code below.

If I want to call ReadFileFromAssets method from CreateMyDb.java, How should I call,What is the context param I should pass? I am trying it make it work but in vain.
Thanks

```
public class ReadFromAssets extends Activity {
private static final String splitBy = ",";
private static int ID_Count = 6;
private static final String ObjName =  "Question";
private static String NewObjName = "";

    public void ReadFileFromAssets(Context myContext) {

        //read from assets
        myContext.getAssets();
        AssetManager assetManager = myContext.getAssets();
        InputStreamReader is = null;
        try {
            is = new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("questions.csv"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
           try {
            reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           String line;
           try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                NewObjName = ObjName+ID_Count;
                String[] QDetails = line.split(splitBy);
                Question NewObjName=new Question(QDetails[0],QDetails[1],QDetails[2],QDetails[3],QDetails[4],QDetails[5], QDetails[6]);
                CreateMyDb db=new CreateMyDb (this);    
                db.AddToDB(NewObjName);
                ID_Count = ID_Count+1;
                   }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //use assets however
    }
    }
```

In the CreateMyDb.java file, I am calling the same method as ,

```
   private void addQuestions(){ 
    ReadFromAssets ReadCsv = new ReadFromAssets(); 
    ReadCsv.ReadFileFromAssets();//what should I pass as context here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most inmediate solution is pass the context of your activity to this class. Is that possible?

If you don't want to pass parameters, you can create an Application class to get the context of the application wherever you want.

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application
{
     private static ApplicationClass myAppClass;

     @Override
     public void onCreate()
     {
          super.onCreate();

          myAppClass = this;
     }

     public static ApplicationClass getMyAppClass()
     {
          return myAppClass;
     }
}
```

Then you must add the next line in the ManifestFile under the label

```
android:name="com.yourapp.ApplicationClass"
```

Now, you can call in you method **ApplicationClass.getMyAppCLass().getAssets()** without passing any context.

I must say that in this case the Application class is not used in the correct way. This class type is used to keep the application state, but is the only way I can think to do what you want without passing any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

pass the context of that class where you are accessing this class method
ReadCsv.ReadFileFromAssets(CreateMyDb.this);
 if the CreateMyDb class extend from activity or fragementactivity it obviously have the context of that activity too so pass the context of the class where you are accessing this thank you may be its help you